# Storage Permission changed when update code on server

Tags: php, laravel, server, permissions

I am facing one major issue in laravel. I have total 2 server one is beta and other is live. When I am uploading code on beta version then it works fine, but when I upload code from beta to live then storage permission automatically change and give me errors.

If I set the manually permission to the storage folder on live then it will work fine. But its not proper way to set manually condition every time.

Comment: Why do you need to change the permission every time?

Comment: how do you update your code from beta server to live server?

Comment: this is cache issue and it happened with me too. just use this trick: in route.php make a route for clearing the cache like `ROute::get('/cache-clear',function(){ Artisan::call('config:cache'); Artisan::call('cache:clear'); Artisan::call('route:clear')})` and just visit this route when you update the code on live server

Comment: @TrickStar How do you update the servers tell me the process, I can see there is issue on the process

Comment: Code is auto-updated every hour through git.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git than run this command

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

On local and both the server on the root of your project this will stop the transferring of permission.

Comment: Already done on local and live server but still we are facing the same issue.

Comment: What about beta server because you are facing an issue between beta and live server. Have you run this command on the beta server?

Comment: we push our code from our system to git then merge our code into beta server after 1 hr one crone will run and update our beta code on live.

Comment: Its ok but code is also on the beta server so you have to run this command on the beta server because permission transfer issue is in the beta server. Can you confirm one thing that crone job is running by root user or any other user?